# How do I see the GPU's bottleneck in a complex algorithm?

Tags: performance, opengl, gpgpu

I'm using GLSL fragment shaders for GPGPU calculations (I have my reasons).

In nSight I see that I'm doing 1600 drawcalls per frame.

There could be 3 bottlenecks:

- Fillrate
- Just too many drawcalls
- GPU stalls due to my GPU->CPU downloads and CPU->GPU uploads

**How do I find which one it is?**

If my algorithm was simple (e.g. a gaussian blur or something), I could force the viewport of each drawcall to be 1x1, and depending on the speed change, I could rule out a fillrate problem.

In my case, though, that would require changing the entire algorithm.

Comment: https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/693679-using-gpu-profiling-to-find-bottlenecks/ may be a helpful link.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're mentioning Nvidia NSight tool, you could try to follow the procedures explained in the following Nvidia blog post.

It explains how to read and understand hardware performance counters to interpret performance bottlenecks.

The Peak-Performance-Percentage Analysis Method for Optimizing Any GPU Workload :

https://devblogs.nvidia.com/the-peak-performance-analysis-method-for-optimizing-any-gpu-workload/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding the one, change the ways to calculate.

```
I'm using GLSL fragment shaders for GPGPU calculations (I have my reasons).
```

I am not sure what your OpenGL version is but using computer shader over FS will solve the issue

```
In nSight I see that I'm doing 1600 drawcalls per frame.
```

Do you mean actual OpenGL drawcalls? it muse be one of reasons for sure. You may draw something on FBOs to calculate them using GPU. That is the big difference between Computer Shader & Fragment Shader. Draw calls always slow down the program but Computer shader.

> An architectural advantage of compute shaders for image processing is
>   that they skip the ROP(Render output unit) step. It's very likely that writes from pixel
>   shaders go through all the regular blending hardware even if you don't
>   use it.

If you have to use FS somehow, then

1. try to find reduce the drawcalls.
2. find the way to store data that is being calculated. 
   It would be like using render textures as a memory, if you need to change vertices using RTTs, you would have to load textures as position, velocity or whatever you need to change vertices or its attributes like normal/color.

To find the actual reason, better use GPU& GPU profilers depending on your chipset and OS.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I mean actual OpenGL drawcalls and I draw to FBOs. Can you please point me to a reference on the "compute shaders don't slow down, unlike draw calls" thing? Also, I don't understand the "find the way to store data that is being calculated." part.

Comment: @StefanMonov I added extra information. Let me know if still not clear.